# Should questions covered in the "quick start" guide be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

There are already a number of questions covered by the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quick-start-guide) on the Raspberry Pi site.  Should questions covered by this be considered off-topic?

Answer (score 8):

### No.

The goal of Stack Exchange is to be a repository of useful information. Even if that information could be found easily from a Google search.

Our goal as a site should be **the** resource that first appears in Google. No matter the question.

[Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/184498)

> So perhaps in the future, the next time somebody asks how many variables can be put on a page, we should kindly embrace them, and not send them on to Google. Stack Overflow is the ultimate destination — not Google. Sorry, Larry and Sergey.

Comment: "The goal of Stack Exchange is to be a repository of information"
That's not quite accurate.  The goal of SE is to be a repository of useful information.  If information is basic, it may not be a good fit for the site.  Just because it's information doesn't mean it belongs here.

Comment: @jandjorgensen Just because it is basic information does not make it useless information.

Comment: I did not say it was useless.  Just because of a piece of information is useful does not mean it belongs on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @jandjorgensen I added a link and quote to a meta answer that addresses this question.

Comment: Furthermore, people could be asking for clarification or further explanation of "basic" topics.

Comment: They could, and should, ask for further clarification of basic topics if it isn't covered by the basic topic itself.