# How can we encourage basic research?

Tags: discussion

I seem to find a lot of questions where the asker has not done basic research. Sometimes the answer is all over the web, sometimes the question is even a duplicate of what we have already got.

Do we want or need that kind of questions here? Should we try to encourage basic research? If so, how could we go about doing that?

Comment: If it is the same as a question that is already on the site, just flag it as duplicate.  That mechanism already exists.

Comment: related: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14/150634

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure there is any way to accomplish this. Especially when you look at the ratio of new users on this site. I agree that it would make it more enjoyable for those of us who have more experience both with the site and with the Pi, but for the long term success of the site perhaps we should look at this not as a problem, but as an opportunity to help and teach these users. After all I would venture a guess that like me you are here because you are trying to help others. One tip I would give you is don't feel the need to address everyone of these weak questions. It is okay to skip it and ssy tomorrow or to let some one else handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure no one of us wants duplicates within the [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) because we all hate redundant work.

Now to the questions that are answered anywhere else on the net, but didn't appear on the stack yet: I think we should keep them.

- In case we want the stack to be a comprehensive and reliable source for expert knowledge about the RPi, sustainability of this data has to be independent of other sources. We all know those frustrating dead links.
- In case we want the stack to be a fast, high responsive Q & A platform about the RPi: The questioner just turned to us with a problem he can't solve with the information available on the stack, so let's solve it.

But I agree, that we need to encourage basic research (and you will never ever get rid of this task). I think best is to lead by example and to point out missing research in an objective and friendly manner.